# matrix multiplication hadoop code does not work for large matrices - Spill failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do this large matrix multiplication. The code below works fine, but when I try it for large matrices, I get the below error. Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong with my input file (no weird characters etc).

Also, would like to mention that after running for some time, it crashes with the following error, and also I get a prompt on my Ubuntu system saying that the file system root only has around 360 Mb. Is it only because of the space issue that the crash is happening?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class OneStepMatrixMultiplication {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            int m = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("m"));
            int p = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("p"));
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] indicesAndValue = line.split(",");
            Text outputKey = new Text();
            Text outputValue = new Text();
            if (indicesAndValue[0].equals("A")) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    outputKey.set(indicesAndValue[1] + "," + k);
                    outputValue.set("A," + indicesAndValue[2] + "," + indicesAndValue[3]);
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    outputKey.set(i + "," + indicesAndValue[2]);
                    outputValue.set("B," + indicesAndValue[1] + "," + indicesAndValue[3]);
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] value;
            HashMap<Integer, Float> hashA = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
            HashMap<Integer, Float> hashB = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();

            for (Text val : values) 
            {
                value = val.toString().split(",");

                if (value[0].equals("A")) 
                {
                    hashA.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                } else 
                {
                    hashB.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                }
            }

            int n = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("n"));
            float result = 0.0f;
            float a_ij;
            float b_jk;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            {
                a_ij = hashA.containsKey(j) ? hashA.get(j) : 0.0f;
                b_jk = hashB.containsKey(j) ? hashB.get(j) : 0.0f;
                result += a_ij * b_jk;
            }
            if (result != 0.0f) 
            {
                context.write(null, new Text(key.toString() + "," + Float.toString(result)));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        // A is an m-by-n matrix; B is an n-by-p matrix.

        conf.set("m", "10000");
        conf.set("n", "3");
        conf.set("p", "10000");

        Job job = new Job(conf, "MatrixMatrixMultiplicationOneStep");
        job.setJarByClass(OneStepMatrixMultiplication.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Error

```
5/05/31 18:45:35 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1019087739_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Spill failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your

```
hadoop.tmp.dir
```

to a location with sufficient storage.